# Query about a deleted answer

Tags: deleted-answers, discussion

Please check [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2823/shortest-way-to-reverse-a-number) question which was migrated from SO. When I go to the original post in SO, I see that my answer is deleted. And a link to FAQ why the answer is deleted. I understand the reason of deletion. My answer is exactly the same logic of another answer which was posted before me, and thus my answer is not adding anything valuable.

Now this is what actually happened. When I saw the question I started to write some code to test my logic. When I came back to browser I saw the notification that 3 new answers are posted. Instead of refreshing the page I posted my answer. Then I saw that another answer is of exactly the same logic, the only difference is that was written in Python like pseudo code, and mine was written in C. So I decided to keep my answer.

Now my concern, does that mean I was trying to cheat? Please note that if the community decides that my answer should be deleted then I have no objection against the SO community. I am only curious what should I do in similar cases.

Comment: I can see the answer now, so perhaps it was a mistake?

Comment: The answer is present in codegolf, but if I click the SO link then I see this is deleted.

Comment: For me it says "0 answers" on SO, perhaps someone cleaned it all.

Comment: May be. I can't see other answers too. But in that case the link to why the answer is deleted, see this faq http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion is a little bit misleading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is all due to the migration: *all* answers, not only yours, were moved to the other site and then were deleted from SO. You simply cannot see the other deleted answers.

(What FAQ are you being linked to? That might need some enhancements to describe this situation.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. This is the faq: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion. Yes I also think that this is misleading.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure there was no implication that you were trying to cheat.

It's a very competitive business writing answers to SO questions and I can easily believe from the time difference that Kiril was just a little faster typing his answer.

After the event, there were some obvious similarities, but as Kiril said "it could be done in any language, because it's just a math method."

If the same thing happens again, maybe *you'll* be faster.